# see the mongo db changes in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I connect to the mongo db by nodejs with this code:

```
url = require("url"),
emitter = require("events").EventEmitter,
assert = require("assert"),

mongo = require("mongodb"),
Cursor = mongo.Cursor;

var uristring = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test"; 
var mongoUrl = url.parse (uristring);


mongo.MongoClient.connect (uristring, function (err, db) { 
        db.collection ("test", function (err,collection) {
        collection.find({},{name:1,_id:0}).toArray(function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);
          });
    });
});
```

but when i inset something to database i should have a query again to show the changes.
the database updated every millisecond by python. how to see changes?should i use socket io between my database and node? how?

Comment: Short answer: What you want is impossible at the moment. Longer answer: You can use [capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) and use a tailable cursor.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg so what socket io does?i don't know but i think that the socket io is a connection that never disconnected...

Comment: May well be - but being connected does not mean that there is a protocol for communication established. You would not expect your voice message system to start a conversation with you, even when you called it and you have a connection, do you? To put it differently: When you connect to an SMTP server using a mongoclient, you would not expect the SMTP server to give reasonable answers.

Comment: you could poll from the client, also the Node.js framework Meteor has some built in features using socket.io and something they call oplog tailing, might be of use to you.  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver